# using toList operator on a neverending Observable

Tags: java, rx-java

The "neverending" Observable emits a parameter item as soon as the user changes something on the ui.

depending on this item I need to do a request. as soon as the parameter item changes the request should be stopped and a new one started.

```
parameterObservable
    .switchMap(this::search) // to stop an restart the request with new params
    .toList()
    .subscribe(resultList -> {/* do something*/});
```

The Problem here is that, the toList Operator waits for the parameterObservable to complete. Which will not happen.

To make the toList work I could do something like this:

```
parameterObservable
.subscribe(params -> search(params).toList()
    .subscribe(/* do something */)
);
```

But then the switchMap is missing.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
parameterObservable
    .switchMap(params -> search(params).toList())
    .subscribe(resultList -> {/* do something*/});
```

Comment: Sometimes, it is easier than you believe.
Thank you!